# Why ubuntu doesn't use the second CPU croe

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, cpu

Ubuntu doesn't use the second core of my CPU, ubuntu can recognize it but even when the first core is really busy (+90%) the second one keeps in 0,0% of use.

Why is that?
This PC came with ubuntu 16.04 and i manually upgraded it to 18.04, maybe i have and old driver?

Edit Summary:
1: i cannot answer that question, anyways it doesn't matters but My CPU is: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz. 2 : microsoft edge, zoom are the principal problems, edge by it self can make the core 1 of the cpu hit 100% percent of use.

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information in your question to provide a decent answer. Could you update the question to include: (1) The brand and model of computer you're using / (2) what application(s) you are using that have you worried about CPU usage. This will make it much easier to provide a more accurate suggestion or answer 

Comment: Install `stress` and check `stress --cpu 2`. I guess your application just does not use multithreading.