# Why ubuntu cannot use my second CPU core?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel, performance, cpu

I made the same question a time ago and nobody answered me so maybe now someone can help me.

The thing is that since i have ubuntu in this pc i've NEVER seen the second core of the CPU being used, even when the core number one hits 100% of load, the second one keeps on 0,0%.

Some one sayed me that maybe the programs that i use don't are able to use the second core but come on, i used a lot of programs and no one of them are able to use at least a 0,001% of it, so i guess is a problem of ubuntu or my drivers or something.

When i use:

- PCSX2
- Microsoft edge
- Chorme
- Firefox
- Wine
- Gparted
- Several games(Terraria, stardew valley, super fighters, minecraft, etc, etc, etc )
- All the freaking programs of ubuntu itself

I'm becoming crazy, i downloaded god of war yesterday and yesterday it was at 50% speed and 30 fps, pretty bad but something is better than nothing, today it runns at 2% speed and 10 fps for no reason the cpu is at 40% just with ubuntu started.
That remembered me this isue.

please help me !!!!!

Well, my pc:

- Is a laptop
- Got 2 gb RAM DD3L
- Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
- Uses the CPU graphics
- Runs on ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: This won't help you, but minecraft **is** single core - has always been. I've got 16 cores, and minecraft only uses one. Since you've got rather old hardware: you did not enable `nomodeset` or other flags in in grub? (you should not)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339574/why-ubuntu-doesnt-use-the-second-cpu-croe#comment2287583_1339574

Comment: For kanehekili:
Ok i puted a list of programs reafearing that probably some of those could use more than 1 core.
About the grub flags: i don't know, i've never configured grub and for ve honest i don't know how to use it's console, maybe or maybe not.

Comment: For ChanganAuto:
1) I'am using a Ceibal SF20PA2
2) PCSX2, Microsoft edge, Wine, best performance in general
3) when i use stress with --cpu 2, it just increase the usage of the first core to 100% percent, but the second CPU appears unused :(

Comment: What does inxi -C report for your CPU?  Does it see multi-core?  I have seen things like acpi=0 make only one core visible, but that was to get a new machine running.

Comment: What tool are you using that makes you think your second core isn't being used?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the programs you list (gparted, firefox, etc.) are interactive programs and generally do not need a lot of cpu.  It is not easy to tell which cpu core they are using, as most of the time they won't be using any cpu core.  More than likely, all of your cpu cores are getting used, you just not seeing it.

Frame rate has more to do with your gpu than it does with your cpu, but lack of either can cause reduced frame rate.

A tool like gnome-system-monitor can show cpu utilization by core in the resources tab.

If you are noticing your system getting slower, since it is a laptop, it is likely overheating and throttling the cpu to prevent heat damage.  There are also tools you can use to check on that.